# Have Pico turn lights on at sunset and turn off at 2am next morning

Tags: led, pi-pico, real-time, micropython, pi-pico-w

I am still new, but trying to learn.  i have been piecing this together, and i'm not getting anywhere.  i hope this can be done easier then what i have.  the end goal is have the pico get the current time from the internet, figure out the sunset time of that day, turn on the led i have at pins 1 and cycle through pins 16,17,26,27,28. and then at 2am the next morning shut all pins off, and repeat.  below is the code i have so far, and i can not get it to run. Please any help would be great as this is to be a gift

```
from machine import Pin, PWM
import time, random, network, socket, machine, urequests, os, utime
from picozero import pico_temp_sensor, pico_led
from math import cos,sin,acos,asin,tan
from math import degrees as deg, radians as rad
from time import sleep
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

 

ssid = [excluding for obvious reasons]
password = [excluding for obvious reasons]
duty_step = 115  # Step size for changing the duty cycle
WIFIWait = Pin(28,Pin.OUT)
WIFICon = Pin(17, Pin.OUT)

def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid,password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        WIFIWait.value(1)
        sleep(0.5)
        WIFIWait.value(0)
        sleep(0.5)
        pint('Waitng')
    print(wlan.ifconfig())
    for x in range(3):
        WIFICon.value(1)
        sleep(0.5)
        WIFICon.value(0)
        sleep(0.5)
        
class sun:
 """ 
 Calculate sunrise and sunset based on equations from NOAA
 http://www.srrb.noaa.gov/highlights/sunrise/calcdetails.html

 typical use, calculating the sunrise at the present day:
 
 import datetime
 import sunrise
 s = sun(lat=49,long=3)
 print('sunrise at ',s.sunrise(when=datetime.datetime.now())
 """
 def __init__(self,lat=52.37,long=4.9, TzOffset=0): # default Montreal
  self.lat=lat
  self.long=long
  self.TzOffset = TzOffset
  
 def sunrise(self,when=None):
  """
  return the time of sunrise as a datetime.time object
  when is a datetime.datetime object. If none is given
  a local time zone is assumed (including daylight saving
  if present)
  """
  if when is None : when = datetime.datetime(*time.localtime())
  self.__preptime(when)
  self.__calc()
  return time.localtime(sun.__timefromdecimalday(self.sunrise_t,when))#-(self.TzOffset*3600))
  
 def sunset(self,when=None):
  if when is None : when = datetime.datetime(*time.localtime())
  self.__preptime(when)
  self.__calc()
  return time.localtime(sun.__timefromdecimalday(self.sunset_t,when))#-(self.TzOffset*3600))

  
 def solarnoon(self,when=None):
  if when is None : when = datetime.datetime(*time.localtime())
  self.__preptime(when)
  self.__calc()
  return time.localtime(sun.__timefromdecimalday(self.solarnoon_t,when))#-self.TzOffset)
  
 @staticmethod
 def __timefromdecimalday(day,when):
  """
  returns a datetime.time object.
  
  day is a decimal day between 0.0 and 1.0, e.g. noon = 0.5
  """
  hours  = 24.0*day
  h      = int(hours)
  minutes= (hours-h)*60
  m      = int(minutes)
  seconds= (minutes-m)*60
  s      = int(seconds)
  #return time(hour=h,minute=m,second=s)
  CDay = time.localtime(time.mktime((when.year,when.month,when.day,0,0,0,0,0)))
  # change hours,min,sec
  #              y       m      d        h       m       s       w      yearday
  #Sun_Day = ( CDay[0], CDay[1],CDay[2],CDay[3],CDay[4],CDay[5],CDay[6],CDay[7])
  Sun_Day = ( CDay[0], CDay[1],CDay[2],h     ,  m,   s,CDay[6],CDay[7])
  return time.mktime(Sun_Day)

 def __preptime(self,when):
  """
  Extract information in a suitable format from when, 
  a datetime.datetime object.
  """
  # datetime days are numbered in the Gregorian calendar
  # while the calculations from NOAA are distibuted as
  # OpenOffice spreadsheets with days numbered from
  # 1/1/1900. The difference are those numbers taken for 
  # 18/12/2010
  self.day = when.toordinal()-(734124-40529)
  t=when.time()
  self.time= (t.hour + t.minute/60.0 + t.second/3600.0)/24.0
  
  self.timezone=self.TzOffset
  
 def __calc(self):
  """
  Perform the actual calculations for sunrise, sunset and
  a number of related quantities.
  
  The results are stored in the instance variables
  sunrise_t, sunset_t and solarnoon_t
  """
  timezone = self.timezone # in hours, east is positive
  longitude= self.long     # in decimal degrees, east is positive
  latitude = self.lat      # in decimal degrees, north is positive

  time  = self.time # percentage past midnight, i.e. noon  is 0.5
  day      = self.day     # daynumber 1=1/1/1900
 
  Jday     =day+2415018.5+time-timezone/24 # Julian day
  Jcent    =(Jday-2451545)/36525    # Julian century

  Manom    = 357.52911+Jcent*(35999.05029-0.0001537*Jcent)
  Mlong    = 280.46646+Jcent*(36000.76983+Jcent*0.0003032)%360
  Eccent   = 0.016708634-Jcent*(0.000042037+0.0001537*Jcent)
  Mobliq   = 23+(26+((21.448-Jcent*(46.815+Jcent*(0.00059-Jcent*0.001813))))/60)/60
  obliq    = Mobliq+0.00256*cos(rad(125.04-1934.136*Jcent))
  vary     = tan(rad(obliq/2))*tan(rad(obliq/2))
  Seqcent  = sin(rad(Manom))*(1.914602-Jcent*(0.004817+0.000014*Jcent))+sin(rad(2*Manom))*(0.019993-0.000101*Jcent)+sin(rad(3*Manom))*0.000289
  Struelong= Mlong+Seqcent
  Sapplong = Struelong-0.00569-0.00478*sin(rad(125.04-1934.136*Jcent))
  declination = deg(asin(sin(rad(obliq))*sin(rad(Sapplong))))
  
  eqtime   = 4*deg(vary*sin(2*rad(Mlong))-2*Eccent*sin(rad(Manom))+4*Eccent*vary*sin(rad(Manom))*cos(2*rad(Mlong))-0.5*vary*vary*sin(4*rad(Mlong))-1.25*Eccent*Eccent*sin(2*rad(Manom)))

  hourangle= deg(acos(cos(rad(90.833))/(cos(rad(latitude))*cos(rad(declination)))-tan(rad(latitude))*tan(rad(declination))))

  self.solarnoon_t=(720-4*longitude-eqtime+timezone*60)/1440
  self.sunrise_t  =self.solarnoon_t-hourangle*4/1440
  self.sunset_t   =self.solarnoon_t+hourangle*4/1440



def ShowTime(thetime):
    Dyear, Dmonth, Dday, Dhour, Dmin, Dsec, Dweekday, Dyearday = thetime
    timeFormat = "{}-{}-{} {}:{:02d}"
    print(timeFormat.format(Dyear, Dmonth, Dday, Dhour, Dmin,))
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
 s=sun(lat=45.5017,long=-73.5673,TzOffset=-4)
 ShowTime(time.localtime())
 ShowTime(s.sunrise())
 ShowTime(s.sunset())        
        
x=0        
try:
    connect()
    while x<1:
        print(ShowTime(s.sunset()))
        print(time.localtime())
        while time.localtime() < s.sunset():
            pin_led = Pin(1, mode=Pin.OUT)
            sleep(1)
            pin_led.on()
            
            led = machine.Pin(16)
            led_pwm = PWM(led)
            #Set PWM frequency
            frequency = 5000
            led_pwm.freq (frequency)
          
            # Increase the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(0, 65536, duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.05)
            
            # Decrease the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(65536, 0, -duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.005)
            
            led = machine.Pin(17)
            led_pwm = PWM(led)
            #Set PWM frequency
            frequency = 5000
            led_pwm.freq (frequency)
          
            # Increase the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(0, 65536, duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.05)
            
            # Decrease the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(65536, 0, -duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.005)
         
            led = machine.Pin(26)
            led_pwm = PWM(led)
            #Set PWM frequency
            frequency = 5000
            led_pwm.freq (frequency)
          
            # Increase the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(0, 65536, duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.05)
            
            # Decrease the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(65536, 0, -duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.005)
            
            led = machine.Pin(27)
            led_pwm = PWM(led)
            #Set PWM frequency
            frequency = 5000
            led_pwm.freq (frequency)
          
            # Increase the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(0, 65536, duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.05)
            
            # Decrease the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(65536, 0, -duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.005)   
            
            led = machine.Pin(28)
            led_pwm = PWM(led)
            #Set PWM frequency
            frequency = 5000
            led_pwm.freq (frequency)
          
            # Increase the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(0, 65536, duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.05)
            
            # Decrease the duty cycle gradually
            for duty_cycle in range(65536, 0, -duty_step):
              led_pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
              sleep(0.005)
              
        morning = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
        print("morning: ", morning)
        endtime = datetime.datetime(morning.year,morning.month,morning.day,22,0,0,0)
        print("endtime: ", endtime)
        now = time.localtime()
        present = datetime.datetime(now[1].year,now[2].month,now[0].day,now[3].hour,now[4].minute,now[5].second)
        print(present)
        
        while present > endtime:
            pinsoff = [1, 16,17,26,27,28]
            for val in pinsoff:
                #pin_led = Pin(val, mode=Pin.OUT)
                #sleep(1)
                #pin_led.off()
                print(val)
                
                
#pinchoice = random.randint(15,28)
#print (pinchoice)

# Set up PWM Pin
#led = machine.Pin(pinchoice)
#led_pwm = PWM(led)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard interrupt")
    led_pwm.duty_u16(0)
    print(led_pwm)
    led_pwm.deinit()
```

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. No one is likely to debug your code. Break your task down into discrete steps e.g. turn LEDs on; run something at a given time; turn off at a time; get time from internet. This is how a programmer would approach the task. If you have problems with a task ask about that single task. NOTE the Pico has a reasonably accurate clock; I wouldn't bother with internet time - does it matter if your task runs a few seconds early or late? I don't know why you are using PWM, but you should put increase/decrease into a function and reuse the code.

Comment: NOTE there are python libraries to get sunset sunrise times. Use one of these rather than reinvent the wheel. Again programmers write as little code as necessary - there are libraries for many tasks.

Comment: Hello,  thank you for replying, i have tried to use the libraries available for sunset, but i have not found one for micropython specifically, all if the ones int he tool for Thonny state for PyPi.  i would prefer something simple, but again i am very new to python and micropython, so trying to find simple code or understanding what i'm doing has been hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your code like this:

```
from machine import Pin, PWM
import network
import utime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ssid = "your_ssid"
password = "your_password"
led_pins = [1, 16, 17, 26, 27, 28]

def connect_wifi():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        print("Connecting to WiFi...")
        wlan.connect(ssid, password)
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            utime.sleep(1)
        print("WiFi connected:", wlan.ifconfig())

def control_leds(pin):
    pwm = PWM(Pin(pin))
    frequency = 5000
    pwm.freq(frequency)
    duty_step = 115
    for duty_cycle in range(0, 65536, duty_step):
        pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
        utime.sleep(0.05)
    for duty_cycle in range(65536, 0, -duty_step):
        pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
        utime.sleep(0.005)
    pwm.deinit()

def main():
    connect_wifi()
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        sunset = now.replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0)  # Example sunset time (adjust as needed)
        if now < sunset:
            print("Before sunset")
            for pin in led_pins:
                control_leds(pin)
        else:
            print("After sunset")
            utime.sleep(3600)  # Sleep for an hour until next check

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @liaifat85 - thank you so very much for this.  this helped me out greatly.  thank you so very much

Answer (score 0):

so i got the code to work up until power it by a wall outlet.  the code runs to to get the wifi with out issue, but then does nothing else during the time it is to turn on.  if i connect back to the computer and run the code from Thonny, it works fine no issues.  but if a disconnect and plug back in the wifi connects runs, but nothing else.  here is the code again.

```
from machine import Pin, PWM
import network, socket
import utime, time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta, date
from time import mktime, sleep

ssid = [wifi]
password =  [wifi password]
led_pins = [16, 17, 26, 27, 28]

WIFIWait = Pin(28,Pin.OUT)
WIFICon = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)


def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid,password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        WIFIWait.value(1)
        sleep(0.5)
        WIFIWait.value(0)
        sleep(0.5)
        print('Waitng')
    print(wlan.ifconfig())
    for x in range(3):
        WIFICon.value(1)
        sleep(0.5)
        WIFICon.value(0)
        sleep(0.5)
        
        
def control_leds(pin):
    pwm = PWM(Pin(pin))
    frequency = 5000
    pwm.freq(frequency)
    duty_step = 115
    for duty_cycle in range(0, 65536, duty_step):
        pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
        sleep(0.05)
    for duty_cycle in range(65536, 0, -duty_step):
        pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
        sleep(0.005)
    pwm.deinit()

def main():
    connect()
    while True:
        timenow = time.localtime()
        dt = datetime(*timenow[:6])
        print(timenow)
        sunset = dt.replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0)  # Example sunset time (adjust as needed)
        morning = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
        print("morning: ", morning)
        endtime = datetime(morning.year,morning.month,morning.day,2,0,0,0)
        if dt > sunset and dt < endtime:
            print("During sunset")
            LightPost = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
            sleep(1)
            LightPost.on()
            print(LightPost)
            for pin in led_pins:
                control_leds(pin)     
        else:
            print("After sunset")
            LightPost = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
            sleep(1)
            LightPost.off()
            sleep(3600)  # Sleep for an hour until next check

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i will note that when i select the pico in Thonny after the disconnect i see this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 73, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 70, in main
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

line 73 = "    main()"
Line 70 = "    sleep(3600)"